# Faster way to extract patches from a tensor?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, tensor

I am trying to extract patches of fixed size centred at some given position (x,y,z). The code is given below:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,99,(150, 80, 50, 3))
patch_size = 32
half = int(patch_size//2)
indices = np.array([[40, 20, 30], [60, 30, 27], [20, 18, 21]])
n_patches = indices.shape[0]
patches = np.empty((n_patches, patch_size, patch_size,patch_size, x.shape[-1]))
for ix,_ in enumerate(indices):
   patches[ix, ...] = x[indices[ix, 0]-half:indices[ix, 0]+half,
                        indices[ix, 1]-half:indices[ix, 1]+half,
                        indices[ix, 2]-half:indices[ix, 2]+half, ...]
```

Can anyone tell me how to make this work faster? or any other alternatives if you can suggest it would be of great help. I've seen a similar problem solved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901746/4296850, but only for 2D images. Could anyone help me to generalize this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/).

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

# Get sliding windows
w = view_as_windows(x,(2*half,2*half,2*half,1))[...,0]

# Get starting indices for indexing along the first three three axes
idx = indices-half

# Use advanced-indexing to index into first 3 axes with idx and a
# final permuting of axes to bring the output format as desired
out = np.moveaxis(w[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],idx[:,2]],1,-1)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Could you explain a little bit how you solved it?

Comment: @pbellot Please follow the comments alongside the code and the linked Q&As.