# How to parallelly slic several matrixes from a image in form of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Given a image in form of 2D numpy array(etc, `[H,W]`), I want to slic several matrixes(etc, `[N，N] N<H,W`), which locate in different places of the image. **Note that**, to speed up, this operation should be **parallel**(This means that you cannot use a for loop to slic one by one as follows code).

```
for i in range(n): 
   matrix.append(image[y[i]:y[i]+matrix_h,x[i]:x[i]+matrix_w])
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack Overflow doesn't write your code for you.

Comment: My current approach is to use a for loop, which slics matrix one by one. But this serial approach is very inefficient and I don't know if there is a more efficient parallel method. Moreover, I have update question with my code.

Comment: Is there any pattern in how you want to extract the image patches? Or are there just a bunch of independent patches?

Comment: The patches are independent and in a fixed size. Moreover, when slicing I already know the positions of all the patches.

Comment: @MaTiezheng I believe this answer fits your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901186/faster-way-to-extract-patches-from-images

Comment: @Naphat Amundsen Thank you very much! this is exactly what i need.